I didn't understand how the object was instantiated
I was studying code, and I had a question regarding the Main Class, how did the developer instantiate the "AddressDto" without using the "new" operator, is it an association?

Class ApiService 

public class ApiService {

    AddressDto addressDto = new AddressDto();

    // Esse método vai retornar uma classe DTO de endereco
    public AddressDto getEndereco(String cep) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        try {

            HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();

            // criando a requisição
            HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                    .uri(URI.create("http://viacep.com.br/ws/" + cep + "/json/")).build();


            // criando o response
            HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());

            // utilizando o jackson
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

            addressDto = mapper.readValue(response.body(), AddressDto.class);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        return addressDto;

    }
}

Class Main
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ApiService apiService = new ApiService();

        try {

            AddressDto addressDto = apiService.getEndereco("03107040");

            System.out.println(addressDto.getCep());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw  new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}

How was the DtoAddress object instantiated in the main class without the new operator?How was the AddressDto object instantiated in the main class without the new operator?

If you notice, the apiService returns an instance of AddressDto - this instance is created when the ApiService class is defined (the line right after public class ApiService { )

For this reason, it is not necessary to instantiate the AndressDto object explicitly in the main class? @blurfus

It makes zero sense for addressDto to be a field in the service, and if you get concurrent calls to getEndereco, you might return the wrong object to the caller. Make it a local variable of the method.

@blurfus That instance is unused and thrown away the call to mapper.readValue

I don't understand, how can I do this? @
Mark Rotteveel

@MarkRotteveel true (if there are no exceptions thrown ;) )

You don't have to create an instance of it in the main class if you are going to immediately override it with a returned value from a service instance call (i.e. the mapper's instance) - be careful that if you are expecting this variable to be instantiated later on and the service fails you will run into a NullPointerException when you try to use the variable for something else.
It is perfectly OK to instantiate a variable with the object returned from another method or service

You can just remove the field from your class and do return mapper.readValue(response.body(), AddressDto.class); in getEndereco, or declare a local variable in the method, assign it there and then return it.

The AddressDto is actually being instantiated using the Jackson library's ObjectMapper. When you call mapper.readValue(response.body(), AddressDto.class), Jackson takes the JSON response from the HTTP request and maps it to a new instance of AddressDto.
So, even though you don't see the new operator, a new AddressDto object is indeed being created behind the scenes by the readValue method.

My question is regarding the instance of the Dto address of the main class that is inside the try block, Is this instantiation being done behind the scenes?? @Ikhlasulov
